# Why does my image not display on some pages?

Tags: html, reactjs, web-development-server

I am using react-js to design my website. I am making a website with multiple pages, its URL structure is a bit like this:

```
%PUBLIC_URL%/
├── /home
├── /store
│   ├── /prebuilt
│   └── /parts
├── /services
│   ├── /repairs
│   └── /building
└── /about
```

when you are on the pages:

```
%PUBLIC_URL%/home  |  %PUBLIC_URL%/about  |  %PUBLIC_URL%/store  |  PUBLIC_URL%/services
```

the logo in the header displays properly.
But when you go into the sub-pages

```
%PUBLIC_URL%/store/prebuilts  |  %PUBLIC_URL%/store/parts  |  etc
```

the logo image will not display.

All the files that I have edited are in this github repo:

```
https://github.com/LukeCripps/Compusell
```

The location of the logo image is:

```
public/img/Logo/Logo.png
```

Comment: You are using a relative URL, from any document that's further down the tree the URL is not accurate. [MDN's page on relative/absolute URLs may be worth a read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls)

Comment: Your repo contains only zip file. It is not secure to download it. Please provide repo with not zipped files for clearance and readable content.